# SQL/PSQL function to get latest update from inner joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-function

I have 2 tables: `drivers` and `drivers_locations`.
I want to create a computed field in the `drivers` table that returns the last inserted location of a driver.

The `drivers_locations` table has these columns:

```
- id: uuid
- driver_id: uuid
- location: geography
- timestamp: bigint
```

The `timestamp` is in milliseconds since the unix epoch. (e.g. 1673129623999).

Here is my noobish failed attempt at achieving this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_driver_last_location(driver_row drivers)
    RETURNS geometry
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
    SELECT loc.location 
    FROM driver_locations loc
    inner join drivers drv
    on loc.driver_id  = drv.id
    group by loc.location_recorded_time_unix, loc.location, drv.id
    HAVING loc.location_recorded_time_unix = MAX(loc.location_recorded_time_unix) and drv.id = driver_row.id;
$function$
;;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try this: `SELECT loc.location FROM driver_locations loc INNER JOIN drivers drv ON loc.driver_id  = drv.id WHERE drv.id = driver_row.id GROUP BY drv.id HAVING loc.location_recorded_time_unix = MAX(loc.location_recorded_time_unix)`

Comment: it gives me this error: `column "loc.location" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Unrelated, but: using a unix epoch instead of a proper `timestamp` column is considered bad design. See e.g. [here](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the locations by the time and limit the result to one row. You also don't need the join.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_driver_last_location(driver_row drivers)
 RETURNS geometry
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
    SELECT loc.location
    FROM driver_locations loc
    where loc.driver_id = driver_row.id
    order by loc.location_recorded_time_unix desc 
    limit 1;
$function$
;
```

A function that selects from a database tables should never be declared as `immutable` as it can return different results even when called with the same parameter.